# Python setGeometry function

Tags: python, qt

I am working with QT designer to design .ui files.I converted .ui to .py file using pyuic4 compiler and coded it.
When i try to run it,it does not show the ui file i designed.All ui components on form are overlapped . But if i use setgeometry function to locate those components on form then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you doing the layout of the form? I am guessing that you are manually positioning and sizing the widgets.

You should rather use the qt layout managers. Here is some documentation on how to do this:

- [Using Layouts in Qt Designer](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html)
- [Qt Layouts – The Basics](http://Qt%20Layouts%20%E2%80%93%20The%20Basics)